# When I save a plot as PDF, the curve becomes thick and unclear. How can I solve it?

Tags: plotting, pdf-format, save

Using this code

```
f[x_] := 16 (1 + 
      x^2)^2 Cos[(-2 + Sqrt[5]) π x]^2 Sin[π x]^2 - 
   1/16 (2 (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[
        2 (-2 + Sqrt[5]) π x] Sin[π x] + (3 + 
         x^2)^2 (Sin[π x] - Sin[3 π x]))^2 + 
   64 x^2 Sin[π x]^2 Sin[(-2 + Sqrt[5]) π x]^2;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 150}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[0.9], Thickness[0]], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100000, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

I obtain a plot which in Mathematica is very clear and the curve thickness is fine (**right plot**), but when I save them as pdf, the curves get thick and unclear (**left plot**). I also tried *Export* and *save selection as* ..., and they did not help. How can I solve this problem? Any comments are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Try `Thickness[Scaled[0.001]` instead of `Thickness[0]`

Comment: @MelaGo Thank you so much, it works.